# Polar coordinations - problem with r and $\theta$

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates, wolfram-alpha

let's take a look on Archimedean spiral. 
the polar equation is $r = \theta$. [click here to look.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r%20=%20theta)

but $\tan (\theta) = y/x$ and $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$,

so $r = \theta \rightarrow \tan(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}) = y/x$. [click here to look.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%28sqrt%28x%5E2%2by%5E2%29%29%20=%20y/x)

but wolfram alpha shows that the equations are different.

where is my mistake? or this is error on wolfram alpha?

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look carefully, it actually does plot the same spiral. The second plot will of course also plot the spiral's 180 degree rotation (since $(-x,-y)$ solves the same equation).

It also looks to be plotting "numerically unstable" concentric circles of radii $\approx\pi(n+\frac 1 2)$. Presumably this is because of tan's singularity there and a numerical loss of precision that causes unexpected equality. That looks wrong, maybe worth a bug report, but shouldn't phase you.